# How can I use HashMap values to form a String?

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have the following code that maps specific String characters into letters:

```
 String a = "94466602777330999666887770223377778077778 883 336687777";
    String[] tokens = a.split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)");
    Map<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    hmap.put("2", "A");
    hmap.put("22", "B");
    hmap.put("222", "C");
    hmap.put("3", "D");
    hmap.put("33", "E");
    hmap.put("333", "F");
    hmap.put("4", "G");
    hmap.put("44", "H");
    hmap.put("444", "I");
    hmap.put("5", "J");
    hmap.put("55", "K");
    hmap.put("555", "L");
    hmap.put("6", "M");
    hmap.put("66", "N");
    hmap.put("666", "O");
    hmap.put("7", "P");
    hmap.put("77", "Q");
    hmap.put("777", "R");
    hmap.put("7777", "S");
    hmap.put("8", "T");
    hmap.put("88", "U");
    hmap.put("888", "V");
    hmap.put("9", "W");
    hmap.put("99", "X");
    hmap.put("999", "Y");
    hmap.put("9999", "Z");
    hmap.put("1", ".");
    hmap.put("0", " ");
```

After doing HashMap, I want to return a String That coverts my previous String "94466602777330999666887770223377778077778 883 336687777" into "WHO ARE YOUR BEST STUDENTS"

Comment: How can you distinguish `4` (`G`) from `44` (`H`) ?

Comment: You already have a good hint which splits variable `a` into `tokens`. just iterate it and get the corresponding string using `hmap.get()`

Comment: Jecod, I don't think you understood Tim's question. When you intend to retrieve the letter from your HashMap, you will typically call map.get(key), where. So if you are iterating over your string of digits. how do you know when to get key=4 or key=44 or key=444? You have to have some way of making that determination. And if you want decent help..you better share it.

Comment: @pczeus My method returns the split digits(which are in String) as arrays like 4 , 44, 444 and so on.

Comment: @Jecob Solomon try my solution.

Comment: @pczeus & Tim I just wanted to say that my question was not sth that is so trivial and doesn't worth asking for help but I still got downvote.Just joined today and as a new user it seemed unfair to me.I still think Tim didn't understand my question.

Comment: This question could use some work to turn it into a [minimal example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use StringBuilder class to form String.

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned, you already divided your input in strings array.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (String s: tokens) {           
    builder.append(hmap.get(s));
}

String result = builder.toString();
```

Comment: That didn't work. returned: WHO ARE YOUR BEST STnullUDnullENTS. Appears to be a slight issue with the regular expression used, not related to your answer though.

Comment: why downvote? Question is how to get value from map.

Comment: he already wrote, he have string array, he just dont know how to use map.

Comment: @Jekob - Sanky's solution works perfectly if you add this to your entries in the map:     hmap.put(" ","");